# Signal strength drop-off from a geosynchronous satellite as a function of angular pointing error

Tags: satellites, antennas

If we have a compact antenna used to communicate with a satellite in geosynchronous orbit somewhere between the $K_u$ and $K_a$ bands of the spectrum (for high broadband applications where we can't use something like the Iridium network), we presumably need to properly orient the dipole of the antenna with respect to the position of the geosynchronous satellite.  Let $\alpha$ be the angular pointing error of the satellite (some fraction of a degree).  How does the signal strength fall off as a function of $\alpha$?  Or, if it makes a difference, we can uniquely define an azimuth angle $\theta$ and elevation angle $\phi$.

Now, I'm guessing that the answer to this question has something to do with the satellite beam configuration / geometry.  So is it possible for there to be a "typical" answer to this question?  Also, to be clear, here I'm asking about the "form" of the expression for the drop-off in signal intensity as a function  of $\alpha$ (or azimuth and elevation angles $\theta$ and $\phi$), as the exact parameters will likely depend on the precise antenna being used.

Where I'm coming from with respect to this question: I heard recently that is indeed possible possible to send data packets back and forth to a geosynchronous satellite from a sufficiently large boat (or aircraft) with proper antenna equipment (indeed to establish a continuous connection), and I was wondering how in the world this worked?  In other words, in the context of something like a small vessel or an airplane, to what extent is sophisticated inertial navigation equipment required for real-time compensation of rotational (pitch / roll / etc.) and translational transformations on the orientation and position of the antenna?

[3-11-2014] Is it safe to assume that these vessel-to-GEO antennas use circular polarization to avoid issues associated with the relative orientation of the transmitting and (primarily) receiving antenna?  It seems then safe to assume that only the angular error $\alpha$ should be sufficient to estimate signal strength?

Comment: Here's a start:  https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=tracking+stabilized+satellite+pedestal+

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks - I know there are some tracking systems out there and I've seen a few white papers / papers discussing them (e.g. http://www.mitre.org/sites/default/files/pdf/wexler_commercial.pdf).  However, I can't seem to track down the form of the expression for the fall-off in signal strength vs. angular displacement from a "dead-on" antenna orientation.  I'm sure this must be common knowledge though?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Consider how quickly the roll/pitch/yaw of an antenna would change in the context of a small ocean vessel during a storm.  It would be interesting to be able to write down an expression for the mean bandwidth as a function of mean displacement of the antenna (even with a tracking system in place) from a "dead-on" orientation.

Comment: http://www.gdsatcom.com/vsat_patterns.php